# How to get the AlarmManager system service in Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, alarmmanager

I'm trying to set up an extremely simple Android application that will fire a toast message on a schedule (even if the application is no longer running). After doing some research it looks like the AlarmManager class can handle this functionality. The issue I'm having is that I simply can't get an instance of the AlarmManager class. I've looked at probably 30 different examples and they all get an instance of AlarmManager the same way. However, when I try to do the same I get the error "AlarmManager is a namespace but is used like a type".

I've tried creating an instance of the class about a dozen different ways and nothing seems to work. All the resources I've found show don't show any alternatives to what I've tried.

```cs
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) Context.GetSystemService (Context.AlarmService);
```

I expect to get an instance of AlarmManager but instead I get the error that it is a namespace being used like a type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure what your "context" is, but I am assuming you are trying to access it via a static property since you are also using `Context.AlarmService` in the same line of code and `GetSystemService` is available via an context **instance**.

You can use an `Application` or `Activity` context to access `GetSystemService`:

#### Example:

```
var alarmManager = (AlarmManager) Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService (Context.AlarmService);
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I tried it and I'm still having the same issue. No matter what configuration I try to access AlarmManager, I get the same error right away. As soon as AlarmManager is typed, IntelliSense gives me the error that it's a namespace being used like a type.

Comment: @Nickel45 Did you name something else `AlarmManager` (i.e. does your namespace contain it?... `xxxxxx.AlarmManager`?)

Comment: Okay so VERY embarrassing but my project itself was called AlarmManager and that's why I was getting the error. Biggest face palm ever. Thanks so much for the help!